# How does matlab interpet colon notation with vectors?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is `(2:3):2:10)` simply equivalent to `2:2:10` by ignoring the vector, or does it have any further application?

I wanted to created an array consisting of multiple numbers just like `[2,3,4,6,8,9,10]`, but surprisingly `(2:3):2:10` has returned just `[2,4,6,8,10]`.

Comment: If I wouldn't know MATLAB syntax and wrote `(2:3) : 2 : 10`, I would think I'd be creating an array that is a mix of `2:2:10` and `3:2:10`, which would be `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`. So, how did you come to `[2,3,4,6,8,9,10]`? did you want to mix `2:2:10` and `3:3:10`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by Nick, what you wrote is interpreted by MATLAB as

```
2:2:10
```

i.e., the `3` of the first nested sequence is ignored.

What I think you wanted to accomplish was a `union` of two separate sequences:

```
>> union(2:2:10, 3:3:10)
ans =
    2     3     4     6     8     9    10
```

More generally,

```
N = 100;

C = arrayfun(@(x)x+x:x:N, 2:N, 'UniformOutput', false);
unique([C{:}])
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was trying to accomplish more complex array. I simplified it a bit to ask this question. Consider trying to achieve a sorted combination of 2:2:n, 3:3:n, ..., n-1, n, ie. every multiplication of every number from 2:n.

Comment: @user1332355: so including double entries? I.e., `2:2:10` and `3:3:10` have `6` in common; should the `6` therefore appear twice in the final array?

Comment: No. Sorry for not being precise enough.

Comment: @user1332355: I'm pretty sure that the combination of all `x:x:N` for `x = 2..N` *without* repetitions is just equal to `2:N`...Think about it: the union at least includes all `x`, because each new series starts with `x`. And since `x` goes from `2` to `N`, the union without repetitions is simply `2:N`.

Comment: You are totally right. Sorry. Sadly I'm not a native speaker and I'm not really able to translate my ideas properly. Sometimes I give up to easy and oversimplify them without too much thinking about what I have actually written. I'm going to try translating it properly now and think twice before posting, but this could take time.

Comment: Tweaking it to be the combination of all x+x:x:N for all x=2..N should do the trick. It should be equal to 2:N without the prime numbers.

Comment: Looks great and pretty mysterious at a first glance. Never heard of arrayfun() before and I must say that it looks pretty useful. Thank you.

Comment: @user1332355: Indeed a neat little function, but with an added warning: especially for large arrays, a plain loop can be significantly faster than `arrayfun` (unless you're using it in combination with GPU acceleration).

Comment: Good to know since I was told to always avoid loops.

Comment: @user1332355: Since the introduction of the JIT accelerator back in 2003 (or something), what avoiding loops will save you is *keystrokes*, not *execution time*. What you have been advised is not generally true nowadays, in fact, more often false than true. My advice: if doing a vectorization is simple (e.g., you can think of one in less than 10 seconds), use that. Otherwise, always use loops. Should performance  really become an issue, profile. [Iff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) a loop should be the issue, spend more time on finding smart vectorized solutions. And vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation for [Colon](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/colon.html):

If you specify nonscalar arrays, MATLAB interprets `j:i:k` as `j(1):i(1):k(1)`.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Sadly, I can't upvote yet. 
So is there any workaround or other simple way to achieve [2,3,4,6,8,9,10]?

Comment: @user1332355 For your specific case `[2:3, 4:2:10]` but if you want a general answer I suggest you post a new question where you describe your requirement more generally. Also, you may not be able to upvote yet but you can mark this answer as correct.

Comment: Oh. Thanks. I was just trying out colon notation and what was trying to implement Erastothenes sieve using P(P(2:10000):P(2:10000):10000)=0 (while P=1:10000). It seems that colon notation is not as awesome I used to think and that's all I wanted to know. Thank you.